# Excel crash after opening it into vb.net using introp

Tags: excel, vb.net

Excel crash after opening it into vb.net using introp

Followig is my code which i used for importing the data from excel

```
    Dim misValue As System.Reflection.Missing
    Dim tbl As New System.Data.DataTable
    Dim xlApp As nExcel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As nExcel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As nExcel.Worksheet

    xlApp = New nExcel.Application
    Try
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)


        Dim issheetext As Boolean
        Dim sheet As nExcel.Worksheet
        For Each sheet In xlWorkbook.Sheets
            If sheet.Name.Equals(sSheetname) Then
                issheetext = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If issheetext Then
            xlWorkSheet = DirectCast(xlWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetname), nExcel.Worksheet)

            ' get range object
            Dim myRange As nExcel.Range = DirectCast(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1:BZ102451"), nExcel.Range)

            For i As Integer = 0 To myRange.Columns.Count
                Dim cellval As Object
                cellval = DirectCast(myRange.Cells(1, i + 1), Object)
                tbl.Columns.Add(cellval.ToString(), cellval.GetType())
            Next
            For i As Integer = 0 To myRange.Rows.Count - 2
                tbl.Rows.Add()

                For j As Integer = 0 To myRange.Columns.Count - 1
                    Dim CellValue As Object = DirectCast(myRange.Cells(2 + i, j + 1).Value2, Object)
                    tbl.Rows(i)(j) = CellValue
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        Try
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
            releaseObject(xlWorkbook)
            releaseObject(xlApp)
        Catch
        End Try


    End Try

    Return tbl
```

but when debugger cross    `xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)`

its shows me

[image: Excel Crash Report]

and in exception it shows me

> The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is nExcel in this context?

Comment: Its a name of introp object like import nExcel=Microsoft.office.introp.excel

Comment: How about making the app visible before opening, and see if it shows any errors?

Comment: can you pl explain me how

Comment: Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.visible.aspx

Comment: did you ever solved this?

Comment: yes my problem has been resoved

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things based on your code I believe your code is correct:

- Please verify file path **sFilePath**
- Any background popup blocking Excel to launch
- Kill all excel from Task Manager and Restart your computer
- In Window Run type Excel -r and hit Enter key (it will reset Excel to default)